# Directive use both request header and body in akka-http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

For Signature Validation in some API call, I have to compute the **Signature** from request body and compare it with one in the header. As I couldn't find any Predefined Directives can do this job, I came out with a custom one like this:

```
def verifySignature(channelSecret: String): Directive0 =
headerValueByName("X-Line-Signature").flatMap { signature =>
  entity(as[String]).flatMap { bodyString =>
    if (computeSignature(channelSecret, bodyString) == signature) pass
    else reject
  }
}
```

This works as expected.

So I'm just wondering if it could be better.
Is there any **directive** can do this job better?
And is it correct to use **pass**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fine to me. `pass` is a correct way to conclude your `Directive0`, and it is used by more complex Akka HTTP directives (a random example, the [method](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/directives/MethodDirectives.scala#L83) directive).

AFAIK there is no specific directive available to perform the task you need. And this being very simply built as a custom directive, there probably shouldn't be.

A couple of tiny improvements you can make:

1. you should reject with a proper rejection - to make it easier to handle them with a proper response + status code
2. you can flatten the 2 nested directives using `&`

---

```
  def verifySignature(channelSecret: String): Directive0 =
    (headerValueByName("X-Line-Signature") & entity(as[String])).tflatMap{
      case (signature, body) if computeSignature(channelSecret, body) == signature => pass
      case _ => reject(ValidationRejection("Invalid signature"))
    }
```